# Is it possible to replace bearings in Shimano XT bottom bracket cups?

Tags: bottom-bracket, mechanical, shimano

Curious if I can just replace the bearings in my existing cups or if I would need to buy new cups?

If possible to replace them then what are possible high quality replacement bearings?

Comment: What kind of problems are you experiencing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't recommended by Shimano, but some shops use a bearing puller to slide them out of the bottom bracket. I don't know if Park Tool makes one, but you should be able to find one at a specialty hardware store. Once you get them out, you can service or replace them.

Comment: The bearing puller in this instance is different from your typical slider style puller. 

It is much more gentle in how it removes the bearings and is purpose built for bicycle bottom brackets.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.endurobearings.com/bicycle.html

Specifically go to the products section, tools and look at the BRT-001.

Have one, works well.

Comment: Thanks, this answers the second part of my question but I can only mark one as the answer.